# Python QGIS QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerBase 1/8 Circle

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How can I change the shape of simple marker  to

```
simple_marker = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerV2()
simple_marker.setShape(QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerBase.QuarterCircle )
```

not QuarterCircle(1/4) but 1/8 , 1/16  of the circle
or Is it possible to import my custom .svg file into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use a QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer instead of a QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer, and create your own SVG files representing the desired portions of the circle. QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer only works with the pre-included set of shapes and new shapes cannot be added through the PyQGIS api.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have different .qml styles saved out beforehand to disk and load it to the layer with the `loadNamedStyle()` method:

```
layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Temp/myStyle.qml')
```

Comment: can you explain a bit? how can i generate a .qml style to achieve this?

Comment: manually add a point vector layer into QGIS, open the layer Properties>Style tab and set the point style (1/8 , 1/16 circle) then save the style to a .qml file (style>save style>QGIS Layer Style file...(aka .qml)).